# Python Socket Closes after One Connection/Command

Tags: python, sockets, networking

The Client and Server can successfully connect however only one command can be issued. Been at this for a while and wanted some outside help, any feedback or suggested improvements would be great thanks in advance.

Been looking at other posts which suggest I may have prematurely closed the connection but I don't believe this to be true due to the fact the program doesn't throw any disconnection errors though I may be wrong.

**client.py**

```
import socket
import sys
import os

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

##server = input("Enter server IP: ")
##print(server)
##
##port = int(input("Enter port: "))
##print(port)

def send_msg(msg):
    sock.sendall(msg.encode())

def get_msg():
    msg = sock.recv(2048).decode()
    return msg

server = "127.0.0.1"
port = 100

sock.connect((server, port))
print("Connecting to " + server + " on port " + str(port) + "\n")

while True:
    #Send data
    msg = input(os.getcwd() + "> ")
    print("Sending '" + msg + "'")
    send_msg(msg)

    #Response
    #amnt_exp = len(msg)
    #data = sock.recv(2048)
    data = get_msg()

    if data == "exit":
        print("\nClosing connection")
        sock.close()
    else:
        print("Received: \n" + data)
```

**server.py**

```
import socket
import sys
import os
import subprocess

#Create a TCP/IP Socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

##server = input("Enter server IP: ")
##print(server)
##
##port = int(input("Enter port: "))
##print(port)

def send_msg(msg):
    conn.sendall(msg.encode())

def get_msg():
    msg = conn.recv(2048).decode()
    return msg

server = "127.0.0.1"
port = 100

#Config
sock.bind((server, port))
print("Bound to " + server + " on port " + str(port) + "\n")


sock.listen(1)
print("Waiting for a connection...")
while True:
    conn, caddr = sock.accept()
    print("Connected!\n")
    print("Waiting for a command...")

    #data = conn.recv(2048).decode()
    data = get_msg()

    #Exit
    if data == "exit":
        print("\nConnection closed")
        conn.close()

    print("Received '" + data + "'")
    #Command Exec
    call = subprocess.Popen(data, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

    #Output
    output, err = call.communicate()
    call_status = call.wait()

    #print("Output: ", output)
    #print("Exit status: ", call_status)

    #Reply
    msg = "Command successful\n" + "Output: " + str(output) + "\n" + "Exit status:" + str(call_status) 
    print("Sending reply...")
    print("\nWaiting for a command...")
    send_msg(msg)
```

Comment: This isn't your problem, but this code isn't correct. You're assuming that a `send_msg` on one side will correspond exactly to a `get_msg` on the other side, but that isn't true. [TCP sockets are just streams of bytes; they have no concept of messages.](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/sockets-are-byte-streams-not-message.html) A single `recv` could receive half a `send` or three `send`s or anything else.

Comment: How would you go about changing this then?

Comment: You need to come up with a framing protocol—some way to define the boundaries of each message. The simplest one, if your input and output are always just lines of text (and can't have any newlines) is that a message ends with a `\n`. Read the docs on the `makefile` method on sockets to see how you can use that. Or, if you want practice doing it manually, you have to loop around something like: `recv`, then `append` that to a buffer, then `split(b'\n')`, then process each of `lines[:-1]` as a message and stash `lines[-1]` back as the new starting buffer.

Comment: Ohhh yea I understand thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your server loop only accepts a single command, and then it goes back to `accept` a whole new connection, and never looks at the old connection again.

Your output is pretty misleading, because it does print out `Waiting for a command...`. But that's only happening because you have an extra `print("\nWaiting for a command...")` before `send_msg`, and you don't have any output before `sock.accept`. You can see what's actually happening if you make your prints accurate. For example:

```
sock.listen(1)
while True:
    print('Waiting for a connection...') # inside the loop, not before it
    conn, caddr = sock.accept()
    # ... etc. ...
    print("Sending reply...")
    # Don't print Waiting for a command here, because you aren't
    send_msg(msg)
    # And print something after the send succeeds
    print("Sent")
    print()
```

So, now you know what's wrong, how do you fix it?

Simple. We just need a nested loop. Once you `accept` a client connection, keep using that connection until they exit:

```
sock.listen(1)
while True:
    print('Waiting for a connection...') # inside the loop, not before it
    conn, caddr = sock.accept()
    print("Connected!\n")

    while True:
        print("Waiting for a command...")
        data = get_msg()

        #Exit
        if data == "exit":
            print("\nConnection closed")
            conn.close()
            break # go back to the outer accept loop to get the next connection

        print("Received '" + data + "'")
        # ... etc. ...
        print()
```

Comment: Cheers I'll try this when I get chance

Comment: @Nosbor2001 You have a few other things to fix, like handling EOF (the `recv` returns `b''`) and errors, but this should get the basics working. Also, two side notes: (1) you usually want to pick a large port number (at least >1024), because low numbers may already be used, may require root/Administrator privilege to bind, and may be blocked by firewall software. (2) `sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)`. Without this, if you ^C the server and try to start it again without waiting a few seconds, you'll get an error from `bind`.